# Laravel: Retrieve instances of superclass with Eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, polymorphism

Here are my (simplified) models:

```php
abstract class Animal extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $name;
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
}
```

Cats and dogs have several other attributes. I've made animal abstract as each animal will be a cat or a dog, so there will be no actual instances of animal.

Now, I want to be able to list:

- `Cat::all()` should retrieve all cats.
- `Dog::all()` should retrieve all cats.
- `Animal::all()` should retrieve all cats and dogs.

Is this generally possible with `eloquent`? If, yes: Should I use Polymorphic Relations for that purpose?

Comment: Do you use separate tables for cats and dogs?

Comment: As they represent distinct classes, I think I should, shouldn't I?

Comment: That's your decision. Does your superclass need more features than `Animal::all()`?

Comment: If possible, the whole set of Eloquent operations like Animal::find() etc. Disclaimer: If a clean solution is not possible with Eloquent, I can remove the sub-classes and use a property $species in the Animal class, instead. I want to use object-orientation if possible, but I don’t know if Eloquent supports it.

Comment: Do you also have an `animals` table?

Comment: Not yet. At the moment, the tables only represent the objects: cats and dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for that in Eloquent.

If `Cat` and `Dog` have similar properties, a single `animals` table is probably the best solution. You can use scopes to only get one species:

```
class Animal extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function scopeCats($query)
    {
        return $query->where('species', 'cat');
    }
}

$cats = Animal::cats()->get();
```